# Preventing duplicate entry from being added (C program)

Tags: c, arrays

I've a method which adds an entry to the table. The entries are name and addresses of people.

```
int rtable_add(RESIZABLE_TABLE * table, char * name, void * value) {

    table->array[table->currentElements].name = strdup(name);
    table->array[table->currentElements].value = value;
    table->currentElements++;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < table->currentElements;i++) {
       if(strcmp(table->array[i].name, name) == 0) {
           table->array[i].value = value;
       }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

However, if I pass the same name to the method again but pass different address, it should update the address (i.e value) of the old entry with the new one BUT it shouldn't consider it as a whole new entry. For example,

If I give a set of entries -

1) George "126 Vine Street"

2) Ashley "889 Vine Street"

3) George "556 Vine Street"

The program should just update the address of George (i.e the value) but shouldn't add another duplicate entry in the table.

The problem with my code is, the way I am doing it, this is what it gives me -

---WHAT I AM GETTING---

1) George "556 Vine Street"

2) Ashley "889 Vine Street"

3) George "556 Vine Street"

--EXPECTED--

1) George "556 Vine Street"

2) Ashley "889 Vine Street"

Comment: See also [Removing an element from a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954964/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the *for loop* before the assignment:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < table->currentElements;i++) {
   if(strcmp(table->array[i].name, name) == 0) {
       table->array[i].value = value; //change the value
       return 0; //dont add a new one
   }
}
table->array[table->currentElements].name = strdup(name);
table->array[table->currentElements].value = value;
table->currentElements++;
```

valter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the beginning. You're creating a new entry first, adding it to the table,and then modifying the existing entry in the loop. I would suggest searching for matching entries first, and only adding a new one if you don't find anything.

What's happening when you run the code, is that entry #3 gets created and added to the table, and then entry #1 is modified in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing your code does is to insert the passed name and value as a new entry at the end of the array:

```
table->array[table->currentElements].name = strdup(name);
table->array[table->currentElements].value = value;
```

The next thing it does is to go through the table looking for any items that have the same name, and set their value to the one passed in, which in your example will update both the original entry and the one the function just tacked onto the end:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < table->currentElements;i++) {
   if(strcmp(table->array[i].name, name) == 0) {
       table->array[i].value = value;
   }
}
```

Btw, you are strdup()'ing name, but not value.  I don't know if that is intentional or not.