# Removing an element from a table (c program)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've got a method rtable_remove which goes like the following

```
int rtable_remove(RESIZABLE_TABLE * table, char * name) {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int position = 0;
for(i = 0; i < table->currentElements;i++) {
    if(strcmp(table->array[i].name, name) == 0) {
      position = i;
      free(&(table->array[i].name));
      free(&(table->array[i].value));
      for(j = position; j < table->currentElements;j++) {
          table->array[j].name = table->array[j+1].name;
          table->array[j].value = table->array[j+1].value;
      }
    table->currentElements--;
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

I want to remove an entry from the table with the name passed as a parameter in the method. For example, if I have a table like -

1) Mat 298 Vine Street

2) Jeff 998 Vine Street

3) Sun 234 Vine Street

And I pass in the parameter Mat to the rtable_remove method, the resultant table should be

1) Jeff 998 Vine Street

2) Sun 234 Vine Street

Where the 2nd element becomes the 1st, 3rd becomes the second and so on. Further, I also want to free the memory taken up by Mat (table has two fields name and value where value is the address).

The problem with my code seems to be that the way I am trying to free the memory throws up a corruption error. Appreciate your help!

Comment: A function that returns a value should return different values sometimes, otherwise there isn't a point in using the value. This function only ever returns zero; there is therefore no point in returning a value. It would make more sense if you returned a value to indicate 'found a match and deleted it' and also 'did not find a match', or along those lines. Remember, if the function returns a value, the calling code should use it, and check it.  Returning a constant value means people write code to check the value unnecessarily, or omit using it (which means returning it was a waste of effort).

Comment: See also [Preventing a duplicate entry from being added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954430/preventing-duplicate-entry-from-being-added-c-program).

Answer (score 2):

Two things. *table->array[i].name* and *table->array[i].value* are pointers so the *&* is not needed

```
free(table->array[i].name);
free(table->array[i].value);
```

Second. The loop should be till *j < table->currentElements - 1* not *j < table->currentElements*
because you are setting the *j + 1* element:

```
for(j = position; j < table->currentElements - 1; j++)
```

Maybe the second part is not needed if the array is large enough.

You forgot the break statement:

```
...
table->currentElements--;
break; //or return 0;
...
```

valter

Comment: Maybe 'Mat' appears in more than one table entry; in that case, the unbroken (`break`-less) loop eliminates them all, not just the first one found.  It's not that I think you're wrong — I don't; I think you're probably right — but there could be other reasons for what's written.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In a previous question he didnt allow multiple entries of the same name [Preventing duplicate entry from being added (C program)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954430/preventing-duplicate-entry-from-being-added-c-program).

Comment: Hmmm…well that certainly makes a difference, but we shouldn't have to go hunting other questions to find that out.  You already got my +1 because the balance of the probabilities favoured your interpretation, but only someone who also saw the previous (unlinked) question would know that the assumption was reasonable.